# Bottle-WebSocket: How to ensure an HTTP request is from the same session as ws connection?

Tags: python, http, websocket, bottle, gevent

I built an web application using Python Bottle framework.
I used `bottle-websocket` plugin for WebSocket communication with clients.
Here is a part of my code.

```py
from bottle import Bottle, request, run
from bottle.ext.websocket import GeventWebSocketServer, websocket

class MyHandler():
    ...

class MyServer(Bottle):

    ...

    def _serve_websocket(self, ws):
        handler = MyHandler()
        some_data = request.cookies.get('some_key') # READ SOME DATA FROM HTTP REQUEST

        while True:
            msg = ws.receive()
            handler.do_sth_on(msg, some_data) # USE THE DATA FROM HTTP REQUEST
            ws.send(msg)

        del(handler)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run(app=MyServer(), server=GeventWebSocketServer, host=HOST, port=PORT)
```

As the code shows, I need to read some data from the browser (cookies or anything in the HTTP request headers) and use it for WebSocket message processing.

**How can I ensure the request is from the same browser session as the one where WebSocket connection comes?**

> NOTE
>
> As I do not have much knowledge of HTTP and WebSocket, I'd love to here detailed answere as much as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I ensure the request is from the same browser session as the one where WebSocket connection comes?

*Browser session* is a bit abstract since HTTP does not have a concept of *sessions*. HTTP and RESTful APIs is designed to be *stateless*, but there is options.

Usually, what you usually want to know is *what user* the request comes from. This is usually solved by *authentication* e.g. by using [OpenID Connect](https://openid.net/connect/) and let the user send his JWT-token in the `Authorization:` header, this works for all HTTP requests, including when setting up a Websocket connection.

[bottle-oauthlib](https://github.com/Refinitiv/bottle-oauthlib) seem to be a library for authenticating end-users using OAuth2 / OpenID Connect.

Another option is to identify the "browser session" using *cookies* but this depends on a *state* somewhere on the server side and is harder to implement on cloud native platforms like e.g. Kubernetes that prefer *stateless* workloads.

Comment: Inspiring from this answer, I now use JWT for authorization. Thanks a lot, Jonas!